# What is the advantage of having same size RAM of 1 Dimm instead of 2 Dimm

Tags: laptop, memory

I was planning to buy a customized notebook. The option of RAM is not clear to me. 8GB RAM of 1 Dimm is costing $50 more than 8GB RAM of 2 Dimm. What's the advantage of 1 Dimm? Any technical plus side?

Comment: No technical advantage. Larger chips cost more to manufacture, so they sell for more. The advantage is that you have a limited number of slots and if you want to expand later, it might be best to buy the larger. E.G, imagine only 2 slots and you choose 2 @4gB, then later want to expand, so must throw away 2@ 4gB, but if you had bought one @ 8gB ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, there is a technical downside. Most modern laptop are able to use two DIMMs at the same time, resulting in an average 5% performance increase. <sup>*1</sup>

There are also advantages though for using only one DIMM rather than two:

1. You have another slot if you ever wish to add more memory. (Otherwise you would have had to remove the old module first.)
2. One DIMMs usually uses less power than two. Even if that is a DIMM with a larger capacity.

---

<sup>*1</sup>: Yes, I am cutting corners here. I did not even mention the term dual-channel.

Comment: I agree. If there are more than 2 slots for memory (I don't know how likely that is), I would go with the 2 DIMM configuration. If there are only 2 slots, then you have to consider if you might want to add more RAM in the future. In that case, it might make more sense to go with the 1 DIMM configuration.